# Aligning icon with ActionBar's Home button

Tags: android

I have a row that contains an icon on the left and a EditText field on the right. I'd like the icon to be aligned with the ActionBar's Home arrow/icon and the text field to be aligned with the ActionBar's title.

Preferably, the size of the icon matches the icon as well.

Does anyone know how this should be done?

Here's what my layout looks like now

[image]

If I give it a height of 56dp and a padding of 16dp, I get the following

[image]

**EDIT** Here's the XML for the icon-text row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="56dp"
               android:layout_height="56dp"
               android:padding="16dp"
               android:id="@+id/icon"/>

    <EditText android:layout_width="200dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:singleLine="true"
              android:id="@+id/text"/>

</merge>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can visit [Google Design Specification](https://www.google.co.in/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar) where you can get icon size and Left margin of Title.

You can use following margin for `EditText` and `ImageView`

Here following image will more understandable:

[image]

- App bar height: 56dp
- App bar left and right padding: 16dp
- App bar icon top, bottom, left padding: 16dp
- App bar title left padding: 72dp
- App bar title bottom padding: 20dp

---

[image]

- Action area height: 56dp
- Title area height: 80dp
- Title area bottom padding: 8dp
- Description area height: 72dp
- Description area bottom padding: 16dp

Thank you. May it will helps you.

Comment: Following the specification, would it be right to make the icon ImageView 56dp tall with a 16dp padding? If i do that, I get a shift too far to the right.

Comment: Your icon will be `24x24`

Comment: I've updated my post with a capture. Yes, it'll be 24x24 - that's the size of the home button, right?

Comment: I think I've fixed it. I needed both layout_width and layout_height set to 56dp. I had width set to wrap_content earlier.

Comment: Awesome, Keep Upvote and accept if you found helpful this answer. Enjoy :)

Comment: So for the text field to align with the toolbar's title, what width should the ImageView take? 56dp? 72dp?

Comment: `56dp` I think you have to give padding. and play with `wrap_content` of `ImageView`